# how can i create a function to implement lambda from right to left in Lisp

Tags: lisp

I am trying to understand LIsp more by trying different implementation of the language.

I am currently trying to create a function that takes a list of lambda functions and compose them from  right to left and from left to right.

here is an example in case i was not clear

```
(apply-right-left '((lambda (x) (+ x 1)) (lambda (x) (* x 2))) 1)
-->  3
```

thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sds's answer is correct for Common Lisp. I'm more familiar with Scheme, so I decided to write a version for Scheme that adds support for partial application. Basically, it's a generalised composition where if you pass a function, it gets called, and if you pass a non-function, it gets wrapped with a function wrapper and gets called anyway. That's a mouthful, so I'll explain in the examples below.

Here's the function (requires [SRFI 26](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-26/srfi-26.html)):

```lisp
(define (wrap x)
  (cut values x <...>))

(define (call-compose . args)
  (cond ((null? args) (values))
        ((procedure? (car args))
         (call-with-values (cut apply call-compose (cdr args)) (car args)))
        (else
         (apply call-compose (wrap (car args)) (cdr args)))))
```

Sure enough, if you call it using your test functions, you get:

```
> (call-compose (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) (lambda (x) (* x 2)) 1)
3
```

You can even do stuff like (which is like your example above except that the arguments to `+` and `*` are swapped):

```
> (call-compose + 1 * 2 1)
3
```

(This is the same as `(+ 1 (* 2 1))`.)

---

The rest of this post goes off the deep end. It may not make sense if you're new to Scheme. :-)

The key part of the magic is the function wrapper, `wrap`. This takes any value and returns a function that takes any number of arguments, and returns the value with those arguments added (as multiple values). Example:

```
> (define wrap1 (wrap 1))
> (wrap1 2 3 4)
1
2
3
4
```

So with an expression like `(call-compose + 1 * 2 1)`, that is the same as `(call-compose + (wrap 1) * (wrap 2) (wrap 1))`, which translates to `(mv + (mv (wrap 1) (mv * (mv (wrap 2) (mv (wrap 1))))))` (where `mv` is [a macro that provides the same functionality as Common Lisp's `multiple-value-call`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/29385/216)).

You can use `wrap` with function objects too. This allows you to pass function objects to higher-order functions. e.g.,

```
> (call-compose map (wrap +) '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
(5 7 9)
```

---

For even more fun, I've also extended `compose` to have the same behaviour:

```
(define (compose . args)
  (cond ((null? args) values)
        ((procedure? (car args))
         (lambda xs
           (call-with-values (cut apply (apply compose (cdr args)) xs) (car args))))
        (else
         (apply compose (wrap (car args)) (cdr args)))))
```

Answer (score 4):

See `compose` in [PORT/ext.lisp](https://sourceforge.net/p/clocc/hg/ci/default/tree/src/port/ext.lisp):

```
(defun compose (&rest functions)
  "Return the composition of all the arguments.
All FUNCTIONS should take one argument, except for
the last one, which can take several."
  (reduce (lambda (f0 f1)
            (lambda (&rest args) (funcall f0 (apply f1 args))))
          functions :initial-value #'identity))
```

Thus,

```
(funcall (compose (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) (lambda (x) (* x 2))) 1)
==> 3
```

If you want to compose left-to-right, you need to pass `:from-end` to [`reduce`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_reduce.htm).

If you do not want to create an intermediate function using `compose` as above, you can use `reduce` directly:

```
(reduce #'funcall
        (list (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) (lambda (x) (* x 2)))
        :initial-value 1
        :from-end t)
==> 3
```